# TFS 2010 how to limit number of changesets

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is it possible to limit the number of changesets keeping only the last Nth versions ? To avoid infinite growth of the database it could be useful to set "keep only the last X version and discard the older" (I have some projects that the changesets of 2 years ago are completely useless!)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend that approach, you never know when having the old version of a file is going to be useful. Code lives for a lot longer than you think and I look after numerous systems where code from over a decade ago is still maintained.

TFS is pretty efficient at storing code (a mixture of deltas and compression) for more information read [Bill Heys's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billheys/archive/2011/08/12/10161444.aspx) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf destroy` with `/stopat:X`, where `X` represends the changeset ID it 'll stop deleting. 
The ref to TF Destroy is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx).
Ensure you know what you 're doing, preferably with tests: `tf destroy` is a one-way ticket, any action can't be undone.